# Swagger Definition of primitive types

Tags: rest, swagger

Is it possible to define a swagger definition/model for a primitive type? For instance, consider the following

```
definitions:
  program_name:
    type: string
    description: Unique string id
```

However, the above example comes back with many errors (swagger expects a `properties` field for example) and no examples employ any definition that is not of `type: object`.

The intention is to use this as a subcomponent to another model as well as a parameter -- to reuse the already defined component in some way.

Think of this as a swagger typedef

EDIT: According to the spec, a definition object is the same as a schema object http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject, which states that it can accept primitive types.

Also, assuming that primitive types can exist in the definitions section, could simple parameter types (query, path etc.) reference primitive definition types?

Answer (score 0):

A primitive schema as in your example is valid and can be used in whenever a Schema object is expected, for example, as a subcomponent of another schema:

```
definitions:
  Program:
    type: object
    properties:
      program_name:
        $ref: "#/definitions/program_name"

  # This becomes:
  # type: object
  # properties:
  #   program_name:
  #     type: string
  #     description: Unique string id
```

or as an operation body parameter or response schema:

```
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      summary: POSTs and returns a string
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: program_name
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/program_name"
      responses:
        "200":
           description: OK
           schema:
             $ref: "#/definitions/program_name"
```

However, simple parameters - path, query, header and form - do not use the `schema` keyword (they use `type` instead) and so they cannot reference schemas from `definitions`.

This will be changed in the next version, OpenAPI 3.0, where `schema` will be used for [all parameter types](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/OpenAPI.next/versions/3.0.md#parameter-object).